# Using Meteor Framework in Monitoring Application

Tags: java, javascript, node.js, meteor

I evaluate using Meteor Framework in Monitoring Application.

Use case. Java Application running in the cluster generates data. Web Application visualizes this data (charts, etc.)

Currently it is implemented with plain WebSocket and custom pub/sub mechanism.

Java App -> (publishes to) -> WebSocket Server -> (pushes to) -> Web App (Browser)

Technology stack:

- Java (data generation)
- Node.js (web server)
- AngularJS (JavaScript framework)

Questions:

1. Is Meteor a good candidate for the same?
2. How will Java app communicate with Meteor? Java client or write directly to MongoDB?
   Have found this java client https://github.com/kutrumbo/java-ddp-client
3. Is it relatively easy to use Meteor in existing Node.js application?

Answer (score 4):

1. Yes meteor is a good candidate for those tasks! Your project seems to be a quite simple scheme for meteor, not a lot of data to publish and a need for realtime monitoring.
2. It depends on what you do need to achieve from your Java app

   - Java server changing the mongoDB : could be a way [edit] I never tried but now Meteor supports realtime DB publication once the MongoDB is changed externally (not more waiting for the 10 secs delay to be published). So just be careful to what you do change on it from the Java App.
   - Use your Meteor server as the client and pull the values from the Java part which would act as a server. This could be achieved using timers, it is easy to setup a java servlet (or whatever you want) and publish the result from the meteor server side if something interesting happened….
   - Use the java app to publish changes to the meteor server. That is probably what you are looking for, I could see 2 ways of achieving this.

     1. Via a url. Setup meteor with a router such as [iron-router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router#query-strings-and-hash-segments), once your client will connect to the meteor server you will then be able to retrieve the query from the url and do what you want with it. The pro is that is it quite easy to just make a "get" call on the server's url from the java App, cons is that you might be restricted in the data format.
     2. Via this wonderful DDP client to connect to your server, then invoke a method call from that last one. On the server, once the method is invoked just update the corresponding collections and you are done. DDP is really a simple protocol, clients are simple to setup so I would personally go for it.
3. My advise is to use Node plugin within Meteor. Meteor comes with Node already (it's his engine) and if you really need to you can still use node.js modules within, the inverse is much harder.

How to get started:

1. Install meteor on your computer
2. Create one collection test, publish it
3. Create a dummy webpage just to subscribe and display this collection
4. Once you are happy with the result, create a Method for updating the collection from outside.

> ```
> Meteor.methods({
>   foo: function (arg1) {
>    test.insert(arg1);
>   }
> ```

In your java client:

> ```
>  DdpClient client = new DdpClient("localhost", 3000);
>  client.connect();
>  client.call("foo", objectToAdd); // something like this
> ```

You are done, here is a dummy project for adding from your java app an item into the "test" collection. As meteor is responsible for publishing all the content to the clients, you only need now to find a good graphic designer to make an awesome monitoring webpage….

Comment: It is worth noting: if you use oplog tailing from mongodb to meteor, there will be no 10s lag

Comment: @imslavko That's right, since of the 0.7.0, meteor is using triggers instead of polling for changes every 10 sec, this said I never tried and cannot talk about its actual efficiency. But even, I still would rather use a DDP client than changing the mongoDB from another process,I think it is a better way to keep the model and events handled in one place.

Comment: I agree with you but noting that is still important to consider as it could be a simpler short-term solution.

Comment: @FlavienVolken, I am trying to implement the part where u mention
>'Use your Meteor server as the client and pull the values from the Java part which would act as a server.'

But I have not been able to find simpleWebSocket definition from within Meteor Server. Could you please hint at some implementation details / which package to include.

I tried sockjs-client, socket.io-client, faye-websocket but whenever I do a WebSocket mention in meteor server-side code, I get undefined reference.

Will post the code snapshot too to explain my problem in another question in a while

Comment: @harshvchawla I suggest opening a new question for it.

Comment: The issue was resolved when I moved from windows setup to linux setup so it worked like it should (as mentioned in some of the examples).
@FlavienVolken I would have opened a new question per your suggestion to find and document the issue but I am not using meteor as of now. Thanks for your reply.